# Clarke directional derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The Clarke directional derivative $f^{\circ}(\bar{x};h)$ of $f$ at $\bar{x}$ in the direction $h$ is defined by

\begin{equation}
f^{\circ}(\bar{x};h)=\limsup_{t\to 0^+, y \to \bar{x}} \frac{f(y+th) - f(y)}{t}. 
\end{equation}

I am trying to calculate the Clarke directional derivative of

$$
  f(x)=
  \begin{cases}
   x^2 \sin^2\frac{1}{x}     &\text{ if } x \neq 0,\\
   0         &\text{ if }   x=0 \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Since the function is on real line we can take $h=1$ or $h=-1$. So when I applied the definition to get

\begin{equation}
 f^{\circ}(\bar{x}; 1)=\limsup_{t\to 0^+, y \to \bar{x}} \frac{(y+t)^2 \sin^2\frac{1}{y+t} - y^2 \sin^2\frac{1}{y}}{t}.
\end{equation}

Then using the sandwich theorem I could get rid of term only and get

\begin{equation}
f^{\circ}(\bar{x}; 1)= \limsup_{t\to 0^+, y \rightarrow \bar{x}} \frac{y^2 \sin^2\frac{1}{y+t} - y^2 \sin^2\frac{1}{y}}{t}  +2y\sin^2\frac{1}{y+t}. 
 \end{equation}
I tried to use the identity $\sin^2 a - \sin^2 b = \sin(a-b) \sin(a+b)$, but I don't have any idea about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\epi}{{\bf epi}\,}\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}$At any point $x \neq 0$, $f$ is continuously differentiable, therefore the Clarke directional derivative is (see [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269548/clakre-subdifferential-of-a-continuously-differentiable-function))
$$
f^\circ(x; h) = f'(x)h = -2\sin\tfrac{1}{x}\left(\cos \tfrac{1}{x} - x \sin\tfrac{1}{x} \right)h,
$$
where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ (defined at $x\neq 0$).

It is interesting to see what happens at $x=0$. Fix a $h\neq 0$ and  use the fact that $f(y+th) - f(y) = f'(y)th + o(th)$, by Taylor's approximation theorem (since $f$ is continuously diff/ble at $y\neq 0$).

We have

$$
f^\circ(x; h) = \limsup_{y\to 0, t\downarrow 0} \left(f'(y) h + \frac{o(th)}{h}\right) = |h|.
$$