# Clarke-subdifferential of a continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a point.

Show that it holds:

$$
\partial_{C} f(x) = \{ \nabla f(x)\}\,.
$$

---

**In the following I collect the relevant definitions and notations:**

**Definition.** Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be locally Lipschitz at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The generalized directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the direction of $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is defined by
$$
f^{\circ}(x ; v)=\limsup_{ \substack{  y \to x \\ t \to 0^{+} }} \frac{f(y+t v)-f(y)}{t} \,.
$$

**Definition.** Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be locally Lipschitz at $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\,$. Then the Clarke-subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ is the set
$$
\partial_{C} f(x):=\left\{g \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f^{\circ}(x ; v) \geq g^{\top} v \quad \text { for all } v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\right\} \,.
$$
Each element $g \in \partial_{C} f(x)$ is called a Clarke-subgradient of $f$ at $x$.

---

**My thoughts so far:**

ad $\supset$: I want to show that the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is an element of the Clarke-subdifferential $\partial_{C} f(x)$.

To do this I have to show that it holds:

$$
f^{\circ}(x ; v) \geq \nabla f(x)^{\top} v \qquad \text { for all } v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \,.
$$

Because $f$ is continuously differentiable at $x$, the (regular) directional derivative $f^{\prime}(x ; v)$ exists for all directions  $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we have

$$
f^{\prime}(x ; v)=\nabla f(x)^{\top} v \qquad \text{for all } v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \,.
$$

Because of  $f^{\prime}(x;v) \leq f^{\circ}(x;v)$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we thus have

$$
f^{\circ}(x ; v) \geq f^{\prime}(x;v)  = \nabla f(x)^{\top} v \qquad \text { for all } v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \,.
$$

This demonstrates that the inclusion $\supset$ holds.

---

The other inclusion, i.e. $\subset$, I dont know how to show. Any help or hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the definition of the Clarke subdifferential as the convex hull of limiting gradients:

$$\partial_C f(x) := \mathrm{conv}(\{\xi: \exists\{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}: x_k\in\mathrm{diff}(f), x_k\to x, \nabla f(x_k) \to \xi\})$$

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, for any $x$ and any sequence $x_k\to x$ we have $x_k\in\mathrm{diff}(f)$ and

$$\nabla f(x_k) \to \nabla f(x)$$

so that $\partial_C f(x) = \mathrm{conv}(\{\nabla f(x)\})=\{\nabla f(x)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You've noted that $f^*(x; v) = \nabla f(x)^\top v$ (not sure why you only write an inequality there).

So the subdifferential is $\{g \in \mathbb{R}^n : \nabla f(x)^\top v \ge g^\top v, \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$.

For a given $v$, the combination of $\nabla f(x)^\top v \ge g^\top v$
and  $\nabla f(x)^\top (-v) \ge g^\top (-v)$ implies $(\nabla f(x) - g)^\top v = 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so $g=\nabla f(x)$.

Comment: I have used the inequality because this is obvious when comparing the defintions of the (regular) directional derivative $f^{\prime}(x ; v)$ and the generalized directional derivative $f^{\circ}(x ; v)$.:

The regular directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in the direction $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is defined by
$$
f^{\prime}(x ; v)=\lim _{t \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(x+t v)-f(x)}{t} \,.
$$

Comment: But you are right in the sense that my problem reduces to the task to show that:

$$
f^{\circ}(x;v) = \nabla f(x)^{\top} v \,.
$$

Once I have this accomplished I can argue as you did above. :)

Comment: @mathsstudent98 Ah, my mistake, I misread the definition of generalized directional derivative. But yes I think all these notions coincide in your particular scenario.

Comment: You can argue that, since $f$ is continuously differentiable, $\lim\sup\limits_{y\to x, t\to 0^+} \frac{f(y+tv)-f(y)}{t} = \lim\sup\limits_{y\to x} f'(y,v) = \lim\sup\limits_{y\to x}\langle \nabla f(y), v\rangle = \langle \nabla f(x), v\rangle$?